# Testing Node.js app with Zombie

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express, zombie.js, coffeekup

I am writing a node.js app in coffee-script using the express framework. After exploring a couple of options I finally decided to use mocha and zombie.js. However, I am having a hard testing the UI. For example, to implement a successful user authentication I do the following: see the code pasted here [my_gist](https://gist.github.com/f1bd9ebda405274e2b28)

What I really wanted to do is the following:

- call `get '/sessions/new'`, which will call the *SessionsController* and display the authentication form
- then I'll call the `browser.visit` method, enter the values for the fields and submit the form, which will generate a **post** method
- if the username and password are correct, I'll expect the *SessionsController* to react accordingly and redirect to the right page.
  Unfortunately, whenever I run the tests it complains about `Zombie: require is not defined ReferenceError: require is not defined`. It turns out it doesn't like the two lines in my /javascripts/app.js

  ```
  require("coffee-script")
  require('./tfs.coffee')
  ```

Even when I try to extract any information from the browser after the visit method, I just get undefined values. Apparently none of my assertions is being tested. It just passes the test. Is there anything I am doing wrong? Has anyone testing coffee-script written app in express using Zombie.js faced that problem? what  could be the fix?

Comment: You are running the test with node.js right and not from a browser?

Answer (score 0):

If /javascripts/app.js is being loaded from the browser, you would want to make sure that RequireJS (or some other browser framework that defines `require`) is loaded first, or load them in your HTML document:

`<script src="coffee-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="tfs.coffee" type="text/coffee"></script>`

You might need to wait until the page is fully loaded before extracting values.